# How to use Generics in Mybatis JsonTypeHandler?

Tags: java, mybatis

Can I use JsonTypeHandler to serialize json fields into different objects?
Here is my demo code. I want the type of extinfo to be TestJsonExtInfoPO when type=1, and TestJsonExtInfoPO2 when type=2. Help me fix it. thx

Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tbl_test_json` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '主键',
  `ext_info` json NOT NULL COMMENT 'json',
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Data Object

```java
    @Data
    public class TestJsonPO<T> {
        private Long id;
    
        private Integer type;
    
        private T extInfo;
    }

    @Data
    public class TestJsonExtInfoPO {
        private String info1;
    
        private Long info2;
    }
    @Data
    public class TestJsonExtInfoPO2 {
    
        private String info2;
    
        private Long info1;
    }
```

Mapper

```xml
<mapper namespace="com.example.demo.dao.mapper.TblTestJsonMapper">
    
    <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="com.example.demo.dao.po.TestJsonPO">
        <id property="id" column="id" jdbcType="BIGINT"/>
        <result property="extInfo" column="ext_info" jdbcType="VARCHAR"
                typeHandler="com.example.demo.JsonTypeHandler"/>
        <result property="type" column="type" jdbcType="INTEGER"/>
    
    </resultMap>
    
    <sql id="allCols">
        `id` ,`type`,ext_info
    </sql>
    
    <insert id="insert" parameterType="com.example.demo.dao.po.TestJsonPO">
        INSERT INTO tbl_test_json (`type`, ext_info)
        values (#{type},
                #{extInfo,typeHandler=com.example.demo.JsonTypeHandler})
    </insert>
    
    <select id="selectByType" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
        select
        <include refid="allCols"/>
        from tbl_test_json
        where `type` = #{type}
        limit 1
    </select>
</mapper>
```

```java
@Mapper
public interface TblTestJsonMapper<T> {
    int insert(TestJsonPO<T> po);
    
    TestJsonPO<T> selectByType(@Param("type") Integer type);
}
```

result1.extInfo is of type Map and not TestJsonExtInfoPO.

```java
@Resource
private TblTestJsonMapper<TestJsonExtInfoPO> tblTestJsonMapper1;
    
public void test() {
    TestJsonPO<TestJsonExtInfoPO> result1 = tblTestJsonMapper1.selectByType(1);
}
```

JsonTypeHandler

```java
public class JsonTypeHandler <T extends Object> extends BaseTypeHandler<T> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonTypeHandler.class);

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private Class<T> clazz;

    static {
        mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_MISSING_VALUES, false);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    }

    public JsonTypeHandler(Class<T> clazz) {
        if (clazz == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Type argument cannot be null");
        }
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    /**
     * object转json string
     * @param object
     * @return
     */
    private String toJSON(T object) {
        try {
            String string = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            LOGGER.info(">>>> json handler string:{} <<<<",string);
            return string;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(">>>> covert object to json string failed, error message: <<<<",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * json转object
     * @param json
     * @param clazz
     * @return
     */
    private T toObject(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        if (json != null && json != "") {
            return mapper.readValue(json,clazz);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i, T t, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        try {
            preparedStatement.setString(i,toJSON(t));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(">>>> preparedStatement set string failed, error message:{} <<<<",e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, String s) throws SQLException {
        try {
            return toObject(resultSet.getString(s), clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(">>>> convert json string to object failed, error message:{} <<<<",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        try {
            return toObject(resultSet.getString(i), clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(">>>> convert json string to object failed, error message:{} <<<<",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T getNullableResult(CallableStatement callableStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
        try {
            return toObject(callableStatement.getString(i), clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(">>>> convert json string to object failed, error message:{} <<<<",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a known limitation. Please follow https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/2187 for the updates.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will follow the progress of this issue